# Ajax call response to array apply to data section of flot chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to place the data retrieved from my database into a portion of the success of the ajax call where there is a function to draw a Flot chart. The data returned from the server looks like this:

[[5,29],[6,57],[7,31]]

I want to use this in the Flot Chart "data:" section that should just be a multidimensional array. When I hard code the values everything works great, but once I use the response from the ajax it will not work. I have used the $.parseJSON(data.d) to get it into what I think is the correct format and when I write out to the javascript console it is showing it as an array. And I can log out the values of the array, but for a reason unknown to it will not draw the chart.

Here is the code (data: obj) is not playing nice:

```
function chart2() {
        if ($('#chart_2').size() != 1) {
            return;
        }

        var selless = {};
        selless.LessonID = '5';
        selless.UserID = '8';


            $.ajax({
                url: "Default.aspx/GetChartData",
                type: 'POST',
                data: '{selless: ' + JSON.stringify(selless) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {

                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d)
                    console.log(obj[1]);
                    var options = {
                        series: {
                            lines: {
                                show: true,
                                lineWidth: 2,
                                fill: true,
                                fillColor: {
                                    colors: [{
                                        opacity: 0.05
                                    }, {
                                        opacity: 0.01
                                    }]
                                }
                            },
                            points: {
                                show: true,
                                radius: 3,
                                lineWidth: 1
                            },
                            shadowSize: 2
                        },
                        grid: {
                            hoverable: true,
                            clickable: true,
                            tickColor: "#eee",
                            borderColor: "#eee",
                            borderWidth: 1
                        },
                        colors: ["#d12610", "#37b7f3", "#52e136"],
                        xaxis: {
                            ticks: 11,
                            tickDecimals: 0,
                            tickColor: "#eee",
                        },
                        yaxis: {
                            ticks: 11,
                            tickDecimals: 0,
                            tickColor: "#eee",
                        }
                    }


                    var visitors = [
                       [5, 29], [6, 57], [7, 31]
                    ];

                    var data = [{
                        data: obj,
                        label: "Unique Visits",
                        lines: {
                            lineWidth: 1,
                        },
                        shadowSize: 0

                    }, {
                        data: visitors,
                        label: "Page Views",
                        lines: {
                            lineWidth: 1,
                        },
                        shadowSize: 0
                    }];

                    $.plot("#chart_2", data, options);

                }
            });


        function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
            $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y + 5,
                left: x + 15,
                border: '1px solid #333',
                padding: '4px',
                color: '#fff',
                'border-radius': '3px',
                'background-color': '#333',
                opacity: 0.80
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        }

        var previousPoint = null;
        $("#chart_2").bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
            $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
            $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));

            if (item) {
                if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                    previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                        y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                    showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.label + " of " + x + " = " + y);
                }
            } else {
                $("#tooltip").remove();
                previousPoint = null;
            }
        });
    }``
```

Comment: After `success : function (data)`
`var obj = JSON.stringify(data)` and `console.log(obj.d)`

Answer (score 0):

var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);
The above snippet accesses array element before parsing json.

Instead first parse the json and then access values.
Change first two lines of success function to:

var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(obj.d);

Comment: I guess I don't need to parse the JSON as when I do the above I get "Unexpected token o", but what I can't figure out is why the response won't render the data to the chart in this section.  

var data = [{
                        data: obj.d,
                        label: "Unique Visits",
                        lines: {
                            lineWidth: 1,
                        },
                        shadowSize: 0

                    }

it doesn't like obj.d, if I provide it like this:

var obj = $.parseJSON('[[5,29],[6,57],[7,31]]'); it works